# Proper UTF-8 hex representation for eacute in XML for XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, xslt, encoding

The many charts available online showing UTF-8 encodings for latin characters are somewhat confusing to me.

For example the eacute hex representation is c3a9 for UTF-8:

UTF-8 (hex) 0xC3 0xA9 (c3a9)

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/c3a9/index.htm

So I'm guessing that would make it `&#xc3a9;` if it was reprented in the XML as hex???  Is this representation standard in XML for UTF-8?  The source system is sending it as 'E9' even though they say it UTF-8.  XMLSpy and Notepad++ show it is E9 anyway.

Can you clear the fog for me?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML uses Unicode code points in numeric character references, not encoded byte sequences. Since `&eacute;` is U+00E9, the system is correct.

And to head off your next question, all six characters in "&#xe9;" are valid UTF-8.

Comment: I think you meant  `"&#xe9;"`.

Comment: Any idea why XMLSpy says E9 is not valid utf-8 when the file is opened?

Answer (score 1):

To confuse the matter slightly, Unicode has two representations for many accented letters: composed and decomposed. For E acute, the composed representation is a single codepoint, U+00E9 (represented in UTF-8 by the octet sequence xC3 xA9). The decomposed representation represents the letter and the accent as separate codepoints (U+0065 U+0301). You can convert from one representation to the other using the XPath 2.0 normalize-unicode() function. Normally data is likely to arrive in composed form, but if you want to cover all your bases, you should normalize it to composed form before doing any operations such as equality testing.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Would this be why XMLSpy says that E9 is not valid UTF-8?

Comment: No, that would be an encoding problem. You've told XMLSpy that the file is encoded in UTF-8 when it is actually in some other encoding (or worse, in a mixture of different encodings). Easily achieved by cutting-and-pasting characters into an editor that isn't very smart about encodings.